# How do I manipulate the following trigonometric equation to solve for $x$?

Tags: trigonometry

> $\sin{3x} − \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \cos{3x} = 1$ for $0 ≤ x < 2π$.

I have tried applying both the compound angle formula and double angle formula but am getting nowhere. Please help.

Comment: Hint: Multiply by $\frac  {\sqrt 3} 2$.

Comment: Hint: show your effort.

Comment: Hint: Use the identity $\sin^2{nx} + \cos^2{nx} = 1$

Comment: I'm up to the step: 4sin^2x - 4sin^4x-1/√3(4cos^4x-3cos^2x)=1. I doubt this is the way to do it.

Comment: Please edit, in the question, all the steps you took. If you have trouble with formatting, have a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format with MathJax.

Comment: First, don't be intimidated by this term $3x$. Let $\theta=3x$ and you need to fix the interval (i.e. $? \leq \theta \leq ?$). Considering the comment by @geetha290krm and the fact that $\cos\phi\sin\theta+\sin\phi\cos\theta=\sin(\theta+\phi)$ give you some hints. Remember you are after $x$ not $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}= \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$, you can rewrite the equation as: $\sin\left(3x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\implies 3x - \dfrac{\pi}{6} = \sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{3}$. Observe that there is another solution that is $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$. The remaining solutions come from adding positive multiple of $2\pi$ to each of these values and solve for $x$ until you exceed $2\pi$ when you stop. Can you manage to put together to get the complete answer?

Comment: it's better not to answer questions with no effort, maybe is more appropriate giving a hint